# Select Query result not come when any one select query not execute or result empty?

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, select, join, group-by

I've written four `SELECT` queries to get quantities grouped by `napkin type`. The "b" and "c" query is `NULL` when cannot diverted or income the quantity. So we are not able to get the `napkin type`.

**It's the problem of `a.napkin_type=b.napkin_type and a.napkin_type=c.napkin_type`.**

```
WITH a AS (SELECT
             COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) AS "receipt",
             napkin_type
           FROM hsc_receipt_entry
           WHERE dvn_cd = '15' AND phc_cd = '012' AND hsc_cd = '05' AND trans_type = '1'
           GROUP BY napkin_type),
    b AS (SELECT
            COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) AS "diverted_income",
            napkin_type
          FROM hsc_receipt_entry
          WHERE dvn_cd = '15' AND phc_cd = '012' AND to_dvn = '05' AND trans_type = '2'
          GROUP BY napkin_type),
    c AS (SELECT
            COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) AS "diverted_out",
            napkin_type
          FROM "hsc_receipt_entry"
          WHERE "dvn_cd" = '15' AND "phc_cd" = '012' AND "from_dvn" = '05' AND trans_type = '2'
          GROUP BY napkin_type),
    d AS (SELECT
            COALESCE(SUM(slsc_qty + non_slsc_qty + six_sc_qty + sev_sc_qty + hom_sc_qty + slst_qty + non_slst_qty +
                         six_st_qty + sev_st_qty + hom_st_qty + slot_qty + non_slot_qty + six_ot_qty + sev_ot_qty +
                         hom_ot_qty), 0) AS issue,
            napkin_type
          FROM vhn_issue
          WHERE dvn_cd = '15' AND phc_cd = '012' AND hsc_cd = '05'
          GROUP BY napkin_type)

SELECT *
FROM a, b, c, d
WHERE a.napkin_type = b.napkin_type AND a.napkin_type = c.napkin_type AND a.napkin_type = d.napkin_type;
```

Comment: Please edit your post. It's hard to read and to be honest it's hard to tell what are your asking for.

Comment: the a,b,c,d all query executed it will get the result .other wise show empty result

Comment: please share any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand your problem correctly I belive you should change your final query to use `LEFT OUTER JOINS` instead of `INNER JOINS` (as you did). So in place of

```
SELECT *
FROM a, b, c, d
WHERE a.napkin_type = b.napkin_type
      AND a.napkin_type = c.napkin_type
      AND a.napkin_type = d.napkin_type;
```

use:

```
SELECT
    a."receipt", a.napkin_type,
    COALESCE(b."diverted_income", 0), a.napkin_type,
    COALESCE(c."diverted_out", 0), a.napkin_type,
    COALESCE(d.issue, 0), a.napkin_type,
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.napkin_type = b.napkin_type
    LEFT JOIN c ON a.napkin_type = c.napkin_type
    LEFT JOIN d ON a.napkin_type = d.napkin_type
;
```

Notice I've used `a.napkin_type` everywhere it's intentional since you join everything to table named `a`, this approach removes `NULLs` from `napkin_type` output.